# Implementing FILE pointer in c++

Tags: c++, c

I'm using a C library in my C++ project. For logging, the C library requires me to define a FILE pointer to get logs i.e.:

```
extern "C"
{
    FILE *pFileStdErr = stderr;
}
```

This will make the logs appear in the console window.

However what I really want is to capture the logs from the C library in my C++ class method, i.e.

```
extern "C"
{
    FILE *pFileStdErr = ???;
}

void CMyClass::Log (std::string error)
{
    m_myLogger.LogError(error);
}
```

So how do I "glue" this together?

Comment: Ok, I will admit it. I read this a couple of times and am still struggling to understand what you're asking. You want to magically have anything written to `pFileStdErr` go through your `CMyClass::Log` member instead??

Comment: If you want your C++ logs to go to `pFileStdErr`, you need to modify whatever class `m_myLogger` belongs to. If you want your C logs to go to your C++ class, you are out of luck.

Comment: Yes,I don't want to direct messages to stdout, instead handle them in c++ class.

Comment: Call `socketpair`, then `fdopen` one end of the socketpair and give it to the library. With the other end, read from it in your main loop and hand the input to your logging method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a non-standard extension on GNU: `fopencookie()`. With that, you can define the behaviour of a `FILE` on your own.

Even if you are not on GNU, your environment might provide something like this.

But be aware that you are losing portability if you do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pipe with the [pipe](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/pipe.htm) function ([_pipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edze9h7e%28VS.71%29.aspx) on windows) and then use [fdopen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/functions/fdopen.html) on the returned descriptors to get a FILE* pointer. Then you can set the write end of the pipe as the FILE* pointer for your library and read from the read end of the pipe in your class.

Comment: If a C function ever tries to write more than one pipe buffer worth of logs, which may be as little as 4K bytes, it will deadlock. You need to read in a separate thread and buffer unlimited data.

Comment: And if you go the separate thread route, you need to be extremely careful when designing synchronization with the main thread, or be prepared to deal with partial and out of order log messages.

Comment: if this becomes a problem they can use Overlapped IO on windows or AIO *nix to avoid the deadlock

Comment: The C library uses a FILE*, that's where the problem starts. If you can change that, you just change it to a callback into your C++ library

Comment: I actually can do this and from what it seems, this is what I will do. I wanted to know if there was a "magical" way to do it that I may have overlooked...thanks.